# Disable auto brightness inside app

Tags: swift

I've successfully lowered the screen brightness of my app using this code

```
UIScreen.mainScreen().brightness = CGFloat(0.0)
```

However the auto brightness settings will increase the brightness over time. How could I make it stop adjusting to the brightness while inside my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to disable auto brightness unless the user does it themselves in settings as Apple don't allow you to access general settings. You could have a function that lowers the brightness when something happens, which might work, depending on what app you're trying to make.